# Looking for the formulas of the Cox-F test to compare to survival functions

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In survival analysis, several tests are available to compare two independent survival curves, e.g. Logrank test with different weights, Gehan's test, Cox-F test, Peto's test, etc.

I found in my daily work as a statistician that the Cox-F test has more power than the log-rank tests.

I think the Cox-F test is not the test within the Cox-regression model. It is a separate test.

Now, I want to make Monte Carlo simulations to compare the power of the Cox-F test with the family of log-rank tests.

In order to do that, I need the underlying formulas for the Cox-F test. I ask you to give me a hint where I can find such a formula, e.g. a pdf file, weblink or other reference.

I think this is important with a far reaching impact, e.g. in medical statistics most of the time logrank test is used, but I strongly suspect that the Cox-F test has much higher power.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess the paper ["The Relationship Between Two Statistical Tests for the Comparison of Two Exponential Distributions"](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/wiley/the-relationship-between-two-statistical-tests-for-the-comparison-of-uBg0hbwu3F) by Le (Biometrical Journal, 33)  contains the answer. The very last formula is the one proposed by Cox in his 1953 paper "Some simple approximate tests for Poisson variates" (Biometrika, 40, 354-360).

Comment: Thank you very much!